# Modifying Windows registry from within Linux

Tags: windows, linux, windows-registry

I have a windows dd image that I have locally mounted.

I need to apply a series of registry tweaks from a known .reg file, within this Linux environment. I can't seem to find any tool that satisfies this.

I have found regpatch and hivexsh but they don't seem to do what I need, or I'm using them terribly wrong. Are there any working examples of performing such a task?

Comment: Not sure if this would work but you could try booting the dd image in a virtual machine and then applying the fixes from within the actual windows environment. You might need to take an image of the changed machine at the end. Again, not at all sure if this is possible but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is `chntpw` (it's the same as mentioned in Ben's question, btw). It comes as package (Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install chntpw`) with modern distros and allows listing or editing the registry, given the hive file of a Windows installation. Hive files are `ntuser.dat` in the profile directories of user as well as the files under `%SystemRoot%\system32\config` such as `software`.

From the `man chntpw` page:

```
-e     Registry editor with limited capabilities.
```

Caution: keep in mind that the format isn't officially documented by Microsoft and therefore any third-party editing tools could potentially damage the hives they load and manipulate. **Take a backup!**

---

As for applying a `.reg` file I don't think you'll get around parsing it yourself. It is basically just an INI/INF file with a special first line and sections named after the keys and values that have been escaped according to the type of the value. `@` is a special value name for the default key. The rest is self-evident from looking at the file.

Python comes with built-in capabilities to parse INI files, so it provides a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I’d start having a sniff around http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ as I’m aware it may have some basic tools to get you there.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a GUI tool, you can use [RegeditEx](http://reboot.pro/files/file/325-regeditex/). It is written in Java, so Java Runtime Environment should be installed.

Comment: Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!