# Laptop Keyboard and Mouse Uninstalled

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse

I recently uninstalled the Keyboard and Mouse Drivers through Device Manager in Lenovo IdeaPad Z370 (because the keyboard keeps on typing on its own and muting the audio automatically). I also enabled the Restrictions for Other Polocies concerning devices under Group Policy Editor, hence, the drivers won't be reinstalled when the laptop restarts. The problem is I can no longer use the laptop since the mouse and keyboard are disabled and when I tried connecting an external mouse, it was not installed due to the restriction policy I set to Enabled. Your immediate response is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: On a working computer download and create a Linux LiveCD. Boot to the LiveCD on your laptop and look at [Modifying Windows registry from within Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/567945/modifying-windows-registry-from-within-linux) or do a Google search for "Windows registry Linux" which might help you with resetting the values you have changed by setting the group policy.

Comment: Thanks I will try this one and keep you posted